# Unable to open a file with in a grails project using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grails, groovy

I am using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite and when ever i try to create a new grails project or import an existing projectg i get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuLJW.png)

and when i try to open a file with in the project the editor throws an error and the file doesn't show up , it looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhByD.png)

any suggestions about what the problem is and how to solve it would be appreciated

Comment: GGTS is outdated a long time ago and not maintained anymore. What Grails version are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IntelliJ IDEA. Its best IDEA for Groovy/Grails.

Download link https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/